# How does Dread work in a Two-Headed Giant game?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-two-headed-giant

[Dread](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=140168) has the following ability:

> Whenever a creature deals damage to you, destroy it.

If we are playing a Two-Headed Giant game and one player puts a Dread onto the battlefield, can I attack the other person in the team to avoid losing my creatures?  (I know with certain effects like [Crosis, the Purger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCrosis%2c%20the%20Purger%5d) I can choose who I attack to make them discard a card, but I'm not sure on how Dread would work.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comprehensive rules, 810.9:

> [In a Two-Headed Giant game, d]amage, loss of life, and gaining life happen to each player individually. The result is applied to the team’s shared life total.

If Player A has a Dread on the battlefield, "you" refers to its controller, Player A<sup>[109.5](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Control_and_Ownership)</sup>.  Dread's ability will only trigger if player A is dealt damage.  Attacking A's partner will not trigger the ability.